# update floating label with dynamic value

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have a floating label named `pendingData` which gets created in `viewWillAppear`. 
Then I calculate the value to display on `pendingData` label from tableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Now on each pull to refresh event I must recalculate this value and then reassign to `pendingData` label.
To do this, I must destroy the label and then recreate it. I can destroy it successfully while refreshing the tableData. But since the table get updated through a asynchronous call. I am not sure what is a good place to recreate this label after table has finished loading all the data. What would be the right way to do it ?

Comment: You don't mention the programming language. Objective-C? Swift?

Comment: "Then I calculate the value to display on pendingData label from tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath" There's your problem. The refreshing of the label should not have anything to do with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It should depend directly on the model _data_. That way, you can update it as soon as you have the data - i.e., when you call `reloadData`.

Comment: I am using Objective C. I ended up using what matt has suggested. Since I am new to ios, I was trying to put this question here to see If there is a function or method which I might be able to utilize.